# Swift screenshot observer executing number of times viewController is viewed per session (not once as it should)

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I am using this function to detect a screenshot in Swift:

```
    let mainQueue = OperationQueue.main
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.userDidTakeScreenshotNotification,
            object: nil,
            queue: mainQueue) { notification in
                print("[!]detected screenshot")
        }
```

It is located in the viewDidLoad() and each time I access the viewController it adds another screenshot observer. So if I were to access the view controller twice in the same session, it would execute two times when I take a screenshot. If I were to visit the view controller this function is running four times, it the screenshot observer would execute four times. How do I keep this from being redeclared between view controller sessions? Thank you for the help.

Comment: why not invoke the `observer` from the `AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` ?  In my app, I care more about a count across the app, rather than on one specific screen.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that it seems every example of screenshot observer we run at in the internet use the main queue. This is kind of misleading, since it means that the observer is added in a more general context, instead of the view controller context, which is what you want.

The way to do it would be to add the following to the viewDidLoad (or to the viewWillAppear, or whichever fits better in your navigation flow):

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didTakeScreenshot), name: UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification, object: nil)
```

(You should replace didTakeScreenshot with your desired method's name)

And then, on deinit (or viewDidDisappear...), you should remove the observer:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
```

(for removing all observers)
or

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification, object: nil)
```

(for removing that specific observer only)

Comment: This should be the correct answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked a long time ago, but here's the answer, just in case somebody comes across the same problem. The most simple answer is to override the method `viewDidAppear` and subscribe to your notification there, and override `viewWillDisappear` and unsubscribe to the notification there. That way if you go to the view controller, you subscribe, and if you leave, you unsubscribe. In my opinion, it is not good to subscribe in `viewDidLoad`. The reason is that `viewDidLoad` is not called every time the view appears. Swift only calls the method if the view controller has not been loaded before, so, if you unsubscribe when it disappears, but do not subscribe when it appears, you will not be subscribed because `viewDidLoad` will not be called.